# Sudden wilt of my cucumber plant, need some help ( Not a bacterial wilt)

Tags: indoors

80% of my cucumber leaves wilted overnight, the tricky part is that since the plant is grown completely indoor（window screens installed to prevent any insect get in), there is no chance for cucumber beetles to spread the bacteria, the cutting test does confirm it is not a bacterial wilt. Hopefully this is a watering issue, however I personally think the moisture level of the soil is balanced, watering schedule worked just fined previously.

I were quite upset to find out my beloved cucumber was about to die :(

and Really appreciate any help from my fellow gardeners :)

[image]

Comment: I wonder if the room became very hot.  Perhaps you could move it to a slightly cooler location while it's recovering.  Also, you could try cutting each leaf in half to reduce loss of moisture through transpiration.  Was it repotted recently?  Also I wonder if the pot is a bit small for the size of the plant.

Answer (score 1):

It might be Verticillium wilt or Fusarium wilt. I can't say for sure, but they can give plants dehydration symptoms, despite watering, and they do affect cucumbers.

People often recommend discarding plants, to avoid spreading the disease further, but you can potentially prolong their life with good treatment, fertilization (including foliar sprays) and such.

The rationale behind foliar sprays is to get them nutrients through their leaves, since they may have trouble doing it through their roots, because of the disease. The moisture on the leaves may help the plant to get additional water, too, that it can't get from the soil.

It can infect soil for years. Thrips can spread it from plant to plant.